# Data loss/corruption in vector3f when transferring to GL thread

Tags: android, opengl-es

I want to create AR drawing application using OpenGL as drawing engine. When I try to pass tap coordinates to OpenGL thread, some data (y axis) goes to screen center unintentionally. Where mistake can probably be?

I'm using this as base for my application: https://github.com/googlecreativelab/ar-drawing-java/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/googlecreativelab/drawar . Bug is present in this code, due to size of project I can't copy code here (only main class is 740 lines). In DrawAR class (main class), onTouchEvent (line 661) registers tap coordinates, then passes it to update method (line 432) which is called on onDrawFrame GLThread method (line 532). Firstly I thought that this may be caused by onDrawFrame called more often, then onTouchEvent is collecting tap data, but touch data isn't erased anywhere, so in that case it just should repeat action with same data.
Stroke - whole figure, point - one point in figure.
Here are some logs taken with data changes:

```
2019-01-29 01:47:08.382 8650-8650/com.googlecreativelab.drawar E/mytag: touch down registered: x 657.0 y 1641.0
E/mytag: stroke added
E/mytag: touch move registered: x 657.0 y 1641.0
E/mytag: point added: x 657.0 y 148.0
E/mytag: touch move registered: x 657.0 y 1641.0
E/mytag: point added: x 657.0 y 148.0
E/mytag: point added: x 657.0 y 1641.0
E/mytag: touch move registered: x 657.0 y 1641.0
E/mytag: point added: x 657.0 y 148.0
E/mytag: point added: x 657.0 y 1641.0
E/mytag: point added: x 657.0 y 148.0
E/mytag: point added: x 657.0 y 1641.0
E/mytag: point added: x 657.0 y 148.0
E/mytag: point added: x 657.0 y 1641.0
E/mytag: point added: x 657.0 y 148.0
E/mytag: touch move registered: x 657.0 y 1641.0
E/mytag: point added: x 657.0 y 148.0
E/mytag: touch move registered: x 657.0 y 1641.0
E/mytag: touch up registered: x 657.0 y 1641.0
```

As finger was held in one point, expected result would be all points in x: 657.0 y: 1641.0, but every second y coordinate is 148.0. Tapping different parts of the screen: top- marker goes down to center of the screen, bottom - goes up to the center, center - flickers value -+20 range. Everything is happening only in y axis.

Comment: It's impossible to know what the problem might be without seeing your code. The only thing I could suggest in this case is to debug it step by step.

Comment: All code is in Github link which is provided and main class with key method lines pointed out.